# Pivot multiple columns without multiple OUTERAPPLY

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following two tables. I'm trying to update the second table with the `Notes` from the first table. Right now I'm doing an `OUTERAPPLY` along with `ROW_NUMBER` to get each `Note`. It works, but I don't like it. I know there's a better way than doing multiple `OUTERAPPLY`

**dbo.Notes**

```
FamilyId | ChildId | Note
-------- | ------- | -----
10       | 1       |   A    
10       | 1       |   B
```

**dbo.ChildNotes**

```
FamilyId | ChildId | Notes1 | Notes2 | Notes3
-------- | ------- | ------ | ------ | ------
10       | 1       |        |        |
```

**Current Solution**

```
SELECT cn.FamilyId, cn.ChildId, notes1.Note, notes2.Note
FROM ChildNotes cn
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        s.Note
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY n.FamilyId, n.ChildId ORDER BY n.FamilyId, n.ChildId, n.Note) AS Rank
            ,n.FamilyId, n.ChildId, n.Note
        FROM Notes n
        WHERE n.FamilyId = cn.FamilyId
            AND n.ChildId = cn.ChildId
    )s
    WHERE s.Rank = 1
)notes1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        s.Note
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY n.FamilyId, n.ChildId ORDER BY n.FamilyId, n.ChildId, n.Note) AS Rank
            ,n.FamilyId, n.ChildId, n.Note
        FROM Notes n
        WHERE n.FamilyId = cn.FamilyId
            AND n.ChildId = cn.ChildId
    )s
    WHERE s.Rank = 2
)notes2
```

Comment: Does the `dbo.ChildNotes` table have a fixed number of `Notes` columns?

Comment: Yeah, it just has 3. Trying to get the first 3 from the `Notes` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `OUTER APPLY` at all. Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FamilyId, ChildId ORDER BY Note)
    FROM dbo.Notes
)
UPDATE CN
SET CN.Notes1 = N.Notes1,
    CN.Notes2 = N.Notes2,
    CN.Notes3 = N.Notes3
FROM dbo.ChildNotes CN
INNER JOIN (SELECT  FamilyId, 
                    ChildId, 
                    MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Note END) Notes1,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Note END) Notes2,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Note END) Notes3
            FROM CTE
            GROUP BY FamilyId, 
                     ChildId) N
    ON CN.FamilyId = N.FamilyId
    AND CN.ChildId = N.ChildId;
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://rextester.com/BXTB31497) of this. The result of `dbo.ChildNotes` is:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ FamilyId ║ ChildId ║ Notes1 ║ Notes2 ║ Notes3 ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║       10 ║       1 ║ A      ║ B      ║ NULL   ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: That sir, is awesome! Super appreciate the help!